# How to display image in center and text to float right to image css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i want to display image in center then right to that image i want to display  Company 1 | Welcome admin |Logout

here my problem is am getting this thing Company 1 | Welcome admin |Logout in next line 
can u tell me why this is happening .

```
<header>
    <div style="top: 0px; padding: 5px; background-color: black;">
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:40%">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/JPL_Logo.PNG"  />
        </div>
         <div style="color:#FFFF33;height:30px;float:right;">
             Company 1 | Welcome admin | <a href="~/Login/Create" style="color:yellow !important;">Logout</a>
         </div>
        <div class="cleardiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 0px; background-color: black;">
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard to do this neat, but this is a quick fix. When floating both elements, you can position them with margin. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ttyz8/

```
<header>
<div style="top: 0px; padding: 5px; background-color: black;">
    <div style="color:#FFFF33;height:30px;float:right;line-height:28px;">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/JPL_Logo.PNG" style="display:inline-block;float:left;" /><span style=" float:left;margin-top:-4px;"> Company 1 | Welcome admin | <a href="~/Login/Create" style="color:yellow !important;">Logout</a></span>

    </div>
    <div class="cleardiv"></div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 0px; background-color: black;">@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Navigation.cshtml")</div>
```

Comment: here am not getting the image in center

Comment: You can try and play with the margin-top:-4px; try increasing or decreasing it.

Comment: still am not getting image in center

Answer (score 0):

You can use position style = absolute for the welcome message div and set top and right to where you want it to be.

Comment: if i put position :absolute ,image or for welcome it is coming to complete left side to page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support 
i got with this

```
<div style="top: 0px; padding: 5px; background-color: black;">

        <div style="color:#FFFF33;height:90px;float:right;line-height:28px;">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/JPL_Logo.PNG" style="display:inline-block;float:left;padding-right:17em" />
            <span style=" float:left;margin-top:65px;"> Company 1 | Welcome admin | <a href="~/Login/Create" style="color:yellow !important;">Logout</a></span>
         </div>
        <div class="cleardiv"></div>
    </div>
```